# Migrating Markdown Tables to Rich Text in Contentful creating inline Entries

Tags: typescript, markdown, data-migration, contentful, richtext

I want to migrate long articles written in Markdown to a Rich Text field. I could handle everything but the tables. [In the documentation it says](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/tutorials/general/migrate-to-rich-text/#8-convert-the-markdown-text-in-lesson-copy-to-rich-text):

> Migrate the content into a linked entry which only has a Markdown field with the supported content, which is similar to the action performed in step 8

But I can't get it to work. In the Step 8 mentioned no new entries are created only existing ones are linked. I have not figured out how to create a new entry of type table (which is just one field of type Markdown with the name content) on the fly and referencing it in the Rich Text content. The deriveLinkedEntries() wants to put the reference into a specific field but this is inline and can exist multiple times.

I am able to create a table in the Rich Text field by hand and inline the reference to the content but I want to create it with the migration script and can't figure out how.

These are my content types:

- [Article with old content field and new one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVrqb.png)
- [Table element to be inlined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfNi9.png)
- [Inline Table element in rich text field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tB8W.png)

And this is what I get on the console for a table:

```
{
    type: 'table',
    align: [ null, 'center', 'right' ],
    children: [
        { type: 'tableRow', children: [Array], position: [Position] },
        { type: 'tableRow', children: [Array], position: [Position] }
    ],
    position: Position {
        start: { line: 14, column: 1, offset: 970 },
        end: { line: 25, column: 58, offset: 1660 },
        indent: [
            1, 1
        ]
    }
}
```

This is my code so far (cleaned up for brevity):

```
const {richTextFromMarkdown} = require('@contentful/rich-text-from-markdown')
        
module.exports = function(migration) {
    
    migration.transformEntries({
        contentType: 'article',
        from: ['content'],
        to: ['contentV2'],
        transformEntryForLocale: async function(fromFields, currentLocale)
        {
            let copy        = fromFields.content[currentLocale]

            const content = await richTextFromMarkdown(copy,
                (node) => {
                    let ret = null
                    let didSomething = true

                    node.deriveLinkedEntries()

                    switch (node.type) {
                        case 'image':
                            // ...
                            break;
                        case 'html':
                            // ...
                            break;
                        default:
                            didSomething = false
                    }

                    if (false === didSomething) {
                        console.log(node)
                    }

                    return ret
                }
            )

            return {
                contentV2: {
                    nodeType: 'document',
                    content: content.content,
                    data: {}
                },
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more headaches and good night sleep I found the solution:

```js
const { richTextFromMarkdown } = require('@contentful/rich-text-from-markdown')
const { createClient } = require('contentful-management')
        
module.exports = function(migration) 
{
    const managementClient = createClient({ accessToken: context.accessToken })
    const space            = await managementClient.getSpace(context.spaceId)
    const environment      = await space.getEnvironment(config.activeEnvironmentId)

     /**
     * Creates a simple hash for a string
     * @param string
     */
    function createHash(string)
    {
        let hash = 0,
            i,
            chr

        if (string.length === 0) {
            return hash
        }

        for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++)
        {
            chr   = string.charCodeAt(i);
            hash  = ((hash << 5) - hash) + chr;
            hash |= 0 // Convert to 32bit integer
        }

        return hash
    }

    /**
     * Extracts part from MarkDown that is the table, transfers content into an
     * entry that is just a MarkDown field. Entry is created if does not exist
     * @param table
     * @param copy
     */
    async function linkTableEntry(table, copy)
    {
        // extract MarkDown for the table from the entered text
        const pos      = table.position
        const strLen   = pos.end.offset - pos.start.offset
        const tableStr = copy.substr(pos.start.offset, strLen)
        const id       = createHash(tableStr) // avoid creating same table twice
        let   entry

        try {
            entry = await environment.getEntry(id)
        } catch (e) { }

        // create new since it does not exist yet
        if ('undefined' === typeof entry) {
            entry = await createTableEntry(tableStr, id)
        }

        return {
            nodeType: 'embedded-entry-block',
            content: [],
            data: {
                target: {
                    sys: {
                        type: 'Link',
                        linkType: 'Entry',
                        id: entry.sys.id
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Entry element with a string representing the table MarkDown
     * The table header is transformed into a title for the Entry
     * @param tablestring
     * @param id
     */
    async function createTableEntry(tablestring, id)
    {
        // create entry title from table header
        const title = tablestring
                        .match(/^.+|\n/g)[0]     // first line
                        .split('|')
                        .filter(Boolean)         // remove empty elements
                        .join(', ')              // Column-Names joined by comma
                        .replace(/\t/g, '')      // remove tabs
                        .replace(/[ ]+,/g, ', ') // no spaces before comma
                        .replace(/[ ]+/g, ' ')   // no multiple spaces
                        .trim()

        let entry = await environment.createEntryWithId('table', id, {
            fields: {
                title: {
                    'de-DE': title
                },
                content: {
                    'de-DE': tablestring
                    }
                }
        })

        return await entry.publish()
    }

    migration.transformEntries({
        contentType: 'article',
        from: ['content'],
        to: ['contentV2'],
        transformEntryForLocale: async function(fromFields, currentLocale)
        {
            let copy = fromFields.content[currentLocale]

            const content = await richTextFromMarkdown(copy,
                async (node) => {
                    let ret = null
                    let didSomething = true

                    node.deriveLinkedEntries()

                    switch (node.type) {
                        case 'image':
                            // ...
                            break;
                        case 'html':
                            // ...
                            break;
                        case 'table':
                            ret = await linkTableEntry(node, copy)
                            break
                        default:
                            didSomething = false
                    }

                    if (false === didSomething) {
                        console.log(node)
                    }

                    return ret
                }
            )

            return {
                contentV2: {
                    nodeType: 'document',
                    content: content.content,
                    data: {}
                },
            }
        }
    })
}
```

So basically what is happening here:

- I created a new content model `table` that is only a `title` and a long text field `content`
- we use the position information given by `richTextFromMarkdown()` (see question for example) to extract the MarkDown string for the table from the content
- we generate a simple hash for that string so we do not create the same table twice if we need to re-run the migration
- if the table already exists we inline the existing one, if it does not we use ContentFul's `managementClient` to create a new one on the fly
- with the `sys.id` of this entry we can put a linked entry into the Rich Text field

I hope this helps somebody cause I could not find anything on migrating tables from MarkDown to Rich Text in Contentful.